# Generating 3D models via primitive skinning

Tags: c++, algorithm, model, 3d, skinning

I am looking for a method by which to generate 3D models for use in video games. The idea is virtual primitives that are simply points with associated data for size, shape, material and rotation.

For instance an asteroid might start as two simple spheres that intersect. Material of dusty rock which would tell the skinning algorithm to provide smooth sandy curves and occasional jagged boulders. Probably end up with a sort of lumpy peanut shape.

After that add smaller spheres with material of void or crater, peppered around the object. These would produce crater like areas in the surface of the peanut and the skin would adjust to suit. In the end you would have a semi plausible representation of an asteroid.

Now with that in mind, my question is, are there any decent open source or public domain examples of skinning algorithms that can find the surface of a model and generate a smooth, evenly distributed quad-strip mesh that could be then textured?

Some more information; I'm looking at CSG methods for the underlying models (adding and subtracting volume) then looking at other methods for remeshing the whole thing.

Comment: Have you looked at [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). They have multiple open source geometry algorithms for [mesh generation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/contents.html#part_XI), [processing](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/contents.html#part_XII) and [polyhedra](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/contents.html#part_VII). The [NEF Polyhedra section](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Nef_3/Chapter_main.html) looks particularly close to what you were talking about.

Comment: It is interesting, I'll have to do more research on it. Right now looking through Sparse Voxel Octrees.

Comment: If you want to have scripts that generate 3D models using CSG techniques, there is no better software than [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/).  It uses the aforementioned CGAL on the back end, but provides a script-based interface for parametric model generation.  I've been using it for years for 3D printing, and love it.  It also has a command line interface so you can script it from a unix shell or command.exe.  It will not, however, be able to integrate into your game in realtime.  It will require you to create your models ahead of time, which I'm not sure is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Jestin that is almost exactly what I'm looking for, though I'm afraid since its GPLv2 I won't be able to use it in a proprietary software. :\

Comment: @EvilSpork: CSG alone won't produce organic shapes (and definitely won't produce decent rocks) - you'll need modifiers that can modify/distort initial geometry. Investigate .kkreiger (100kb 1st person shooter), [ken perlin homepage](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/), and [metaballs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs). That should get you started. Also, to make a voxel tree, [you do not need terabytes of data](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF0U8WYbjFQ). You need a recursive formula that defines tree.

Comment: Aye, but at first I wasn't even thinking of a voxel Tree, just straight up voxel data. (for planet wide scales) When I started this trek, I didn't even know about voxel trees. Just arrays. -- As for CSG, no its not the end product, but its a good first step. Get the rough shape of what you want, then apply deforms to it, 'soften' the edges and so forth. have your potato shaped asteroid, take a hemisphere chunk out of it, then apply a filter to make it look crater like. (smoothing, roughening, gouges)

Comment: I've been interested in this topic for years here are some notes --openscad is good but some of the CSG'd models have unwelded edges that mess up in meshlab subdivision. -- you can use unity3d with it's advanced library and easy coding to code shapegen engines, and batch process them through openscad into STL's, just save scad files with shape arrays from unity. I dont think structuresynth can export shape arrays? I don't know if autodesk/grasshopper/blender can do the same as openscad?!? perhaps more reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Skinning is an art more than a scientific process (and so almost impossible to automate) because skinning is a visual approximation of movement. To get something fully automatic, you would either have to assume bone placement or simply assume there are none at all.

Here's an example. This is an open-source project that skins automatically based on the fact that the provided mesh is a humanoid.
http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/fast/

EDIT: Wait, you mean the other way around? Isn't that similar to marching cubes? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes

Comment: Actually something closer to "meatballs" in blender or the Spore creature creator. I'm trying to avoid using voxels due to their inherent data massiveness. On the grand scale, a realistic planet would be just purely insane datawise, terabytes of voxel information. But a few intersecting virtual primitives would be far simpler.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exciting question and no doubt there are many ways it could be done. Personally I'd probably start by getting basic shapes on .obj format, which is easy to both parse and create programmatically, and then do exactly that in my code: tweak or randomize the the vertices you export from a modelling program to create an infinite variety of similar but slightly different objects, like asteroids. Of course if you need more than asteroids, you'd go back to a different .obj file. It's hard to say the best technique for your case since I think some experimentation would be required no matter what you try.